# on_message won't detect any message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am writing a discord bot with discord.py. 
I wrote an initial version but I decided it all needed reorganizing so I moved code to different files.

The code is all the same as it was before but now when I boot up the bot, the bot detects no messages being sent in any server unless the message came from the bot itself.

The main code that handles the `client` is:

```
import discord
import time
from command_list import *
from resource_functions import grab_setting_from_category

print("Main initialized")

client = discord.Client()
token = "BOT TOKEN"

prefix = "!"


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("*** BOT IS READY ***")

    async def server_count_loop():
        while True:
            servers = client.servers
            await client.change_presence(
                game=discord.Game(name=" in {0} Servers".format(str(len(servers)))))
            time.sleep(10)

        for server in client.servers:
            for channel in server.channels:
                if channel.name == "general":
                    await client.send_message(channel, content="Bot Online")

    await server_count_loop()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("Message detected from {0} as '{1}'".format(message.author, message.content))
    if not message.author.bot:
        global prefix
        prefix = grab_setting_from_category(message.server.id, "server", "prefix")
        if message.content.startswith(prefix):
            for i in range(0,len(commands)):
                key = list(commands.keys())[i]
                table = list(commands.values())[i]
                if message.content.startswith(prefix+key):
                    table["function"](message, commands)


client.run(token)
```

In the code there's the `print(...)` at the start of the `on_message` function which I am using as a basic way to let me know if the bot is detecting messages. The print statement prints whenever the bot sends a message in `on_ready` but no messages from other users on Discord are triggering the function.

Comment: Change your token now. Never upload your token to StackOverflow or GitHub because it **cannot** be deleted.

Comment: I suspect the indentation in the question's code isn't the same indentation as your actual code. Anyways, you shouldn't have a while loop + `time.sleep`, it blocks the main discord loop.

Comment: I generated a new token and edited it. Thanks for lookin out, before I posted I repasted and forgot about the token

Comment: Still worth resetting the token though. You never know who will download anything. Anyway I think @abccd has the solution. The `time.sleep` is blocking the main loop, so you need to use `await asyncio.sleep` instead.  Side note, unless your indentation wasn't pasted correctly, the code after the end of the `while True` will never run.

Comment: It was pasted incorrectly and that actually does seem to be the problem. Thank you guys

Comment: Don't forget to answer yourself below with what you needed to do to fix it. [That helps out people in the future with the same issue](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Comment: @squaswin I wrote a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50184218/6622817), an answer that belongs to everyone (ie. the community), and no single individual gain rep from it. LordyLordy, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use:

```
time.sleep(...)
```

Instead, use:

```
await asyncio.sleep(...)
```

`time.sleep` is a blocking call, it blocks the asyncio loop to continue to run. That is why you need to have an asynchronous `.sleep(...)` method.